# How do I use a Yubikey NEO in 14.04 to log into a Google account through Chrome?

Tags: 14.04, yubikey

How do I make Ubuntu 14.04 recognize a Yubikey NEO for Google account authentication?

---

I have yubikey NEO and Chrome version 46.0.2490.80.
I have used the key successfully on a laptop running Windows 8.
I'd like to use it on a few Ubuntu machines to log into Google.
According to [Yubikey's instructions](https://www.yubico.com/faq/enable-u2f-linux/), I have created the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-u2f.rules` with the following contents:

```
ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="u2f_end"

# Yubico YubiKey
KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1050", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0113|0114|0115|0116|0120|0402|0403|0406|0407|0410", TAG+="uaccess"

# Happlink (formaly Plug-Up) Security KEY
KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2581", ATTRS{idProduct}=="f1d0", TAG+="uaccess"

#  Neowave Keydo and Keydo AES
KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1e0d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="f1d0|f1ae", TAG+="uaccess"

# HyperSecu HyperFIDO
KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="096e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0880", TAG+="uaccess"

LABEL="u2f_end"
```

If I then go try to log into Google, after entering my password I see a picture of the yubikey and an error message which reads `An unexpected error occurred`.

I then try to see if the key is identifying itself properly.
I unplug the key, plug it back in, and get the following output from `$ dmesg | tail`

```
[ 2410.138684] usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 19 using ehci-pci
[ 2410.233935] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1050, idProduct=0211
[ 2410.233942] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2410.233946] usb 2-1.3: Product: Yubico WinUSB Gnubby (gnubby1)
[ 2410.233949] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: Yubico
```

The `idVendor` agrees with the `#Yubico YubiKey` line in `70-u2f.rules`, but the `idVendor` of 0211 is *not* in `70-u2f.rules`.
Trying to fix this I amend the rules file so that the line after `#Yubico YubiKey` reads

```
KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1050", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0113|0114|0115|0116|0120|0402|0403|0406|0407|0410|0211", TAG+="uaccess"
```

Note the addition of `|0211` in the `idProduct` line.
I reboot the machine, but the problem persists.

Comment: Adding the udev rule mentioned (see also [here](https://www.yubico.com/faq/enable-u2f-linux/) fixed the `An unexpected error occurred` problem for me. Have you followed the instructions on https://www.yubico.com/faq/enable-u2f-linux/, including enabling `U2F+HID` mode using the `neoman` program from the `yubikey-neo-manager` package? In `neoman`, I have all 3 boxes ticked (OTP+CCID+U2F). For my Yubikey Neo though, the `dmesg` entry is differnt: `New USB device found, idVendor=1050, idProduct=0116`, `Product: Yubikey NEO OTP+U2F+CCID`, not `Yubico WinUSB Gnubby`.

Answer (score 4):

I had your same problem (on ubuntu 16.04), and this worked for me:

Create a new file called /etc/udev/rules.d/50-security-key.rules:

> SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1050", OWNER="root",
>   GROUP="plugdev", MODE:="0660"

Once that file is saved, run

> sudo udevadm control --reload-rules

and then restart Chrome.

The question is old, but hopefully this will save time to someone else.
Source: http://www.sowbug.com/post/131363489376/enabling-yubico-u2f-security-key-on-chrome-for

Comment: This answer helped me discover that, for me, the user that was running Chromium was not part of the `plugdev` group.  After adding the user to the group, the blue Yubi key worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 15.04 above setting up https://www.yubico.com/faq/enable-u2f-linux/

```
cd /etc/udev/rules.d/
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Yubico/libu2f-host/master/70-u2f.rules
```

reboot

Then register the key as per normal instructions.